# Handling Typed string Constants in a Global Struct

Tags: go

I am wondering how best to handle a collection of typed `string` and number constants in a **global** `struct`.

I.e. I like to collect all written strings and magic numbers in one Struct that can be called globally. This is to prevent typing errors and have all settings in one place. I have only found solutions that have a lot of boilerplate, but how is this best solved?

Comment: Look at the standard lib for examples, e.g. [HTTP methods](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.5:src/net/http/method.go), [HTTP status codes](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.5:src/net/http/status.go).

Comment: Note that "string and number constants in a global struct" is a bit of a contradiction in terms because struct, in Go, cannot be a constant and neither can it hold constants.

Comment: Thanks @icza I will have a look at that code.

Comment: @mkopriva I am sorry for the contradiction in the terms, but if you have another way of working around this could you please add an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, you cannot really use a struct for this purpose.  You can certainly declare a common set of constants within any given package and export them for use elsewhere - the `net/http` package is probably the most commonly used example of this for both methods (`http.MethodGet`).

Another method that may or may not work for you (it's tough to say more without knowing specifics of your use case) is the use of an `enum`:

```go
type Building int

const (
    Headquarters Building = iota
    Factory
    Receiving
    Administration
)

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("You are in building %d\n", Factory)
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/WMGGIECq4b3)

I like using a type alias for constants, generally, so that I can restrict the range of possible values to only those I want:

```go
type Building string

const (
    BuildingHQ      Building = "headquarters"
    BuildingFactory Building = "factory"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("You are in building %s\n", BuildingHQ)
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/E_W1PfYX3VM)

Comment: Thanks, I like the use of a new type to restrict the values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @icza comment above. This is how constants are handled in the go lib. They are all in the global space so their names are prefixed by Method... and Status... for those that are related.

Then a convenience method for returning the string is added for the `StatusText(code int)`, but you could use any int in this method.

```
package http

// Common HTTP methods.
const (
    MethodGet     = "GET"
    MethodPost    = "POST"
    MethodPut     = "PUT"
    MethodDelete  = "DELETE"
    // Skipped lines
)

// HTTP status codes as registered with IANA.
const (
    StatusContinue           = 100 // RFC 9110, 15.2.1
    StatusSwitchingProtocols = 101 // RFC 9110, 15.2.2
    StatusProcessing         = 102 // RFC 2518, 10.1
    StatusEarlyHints         = 103 // RFC 8297

    StatusOK                   = 200 // RFC 9110, 15.3.1
    StatusCreated              = 201 // RFC 9110, 15.3.2
    StatusAccepted             = 202 // RFC 9110, 15.3.3
    StatusNonAuthoritativeInfo = 203 // RFC 9110, 15.3.4
    StatusNoContent            = 204 // RFC 9110, 15.3.5
    // Skipped lines
)

// StatusText returns a text for the HTTP status code.
func StatusText(code int) string {
    switch code {
    case StatusContinue:
        return "Continue"
    case StatusSwitchingProtocols:
        return "Switching Protocols"
    case StatusProcessing:
        return "Processing"
    case StatusEarlyHints:
        return "Early Hints"
    case StatusOK:
        return "OK"

    // Skipped lines

    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that, if you do not declare the type of a constant explicitly, it is inferred, and that may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Also, it's not strictly accurate to say that they're "in the global space" - they're exported symbols, but you still have to supply the package prefix when using them, unless you've dot-imported the package (which you generally shouldn't do).  Even then, that doesn't add them to a "global" namespace, it just imports symbols into the current package (and only for use within the specific source file, not all files within the package, I believe).

Prefixing constants is IMHO good practice, but it aids more in usability than in collision avoidance.

Comment: For the `StatusText()` implementation, I would have implemented it as a map, personally.  If I were using an `enum/iota` construct, then I'd have a slice, rather than a map, to hold the values.  You could even have the values in the map/slice be structs if you wanted to enable more complex interpolation cases...but that is probably overcomplicating things in most use cases.